# Redis wont start: Could not create server TCP listening socket 127.0.0.1:6379: bind: Address already in use

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis

I have installed `redis` in my AWS server. I have followed this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-secure-redis-centos-7

```
$ systemctl start redis.service
$ systemctl enable redis
  -> Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/redis.service → /usr/lib/systemd/system/redis.service.
$ systemctl status redis.service
● redis.service - Redis persistent key-value database
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/redis.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/redis.service.d
           └─limit.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-08-26 02:28:25 UTC; 10s ago
 Main PID: 5012 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 26 02:28:25 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Starting Redis persistent key-value database...
Aug 26 02:28:25 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Started Redis persistent key-value database.
Aug 26 02:28:25 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: redis.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 26 02:28:25 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: redis.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

And when I check the `/var/log/redis/redis.log` this is what I see:

```
5012:C 26 Aug 2020 02:28:25.574 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
5012:C 26 Aug 2020 02:28:25.574 # Redis version=5.0.3, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=5012, just started
5012:C 26 Aug 2020 02:28:25.574 # Configuration loaded
5012:C 26 Aug 2020 02:28:25.574 * supervised by systemd, will signal readiness
5012:M 26 Aug 2020 02:28:25.575 # Could not create server TCP listening socket 127.0.0.1:6379: bind: Address already in use
```

And upon checking the ports:

```
$ netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2812/redis-server *
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      2812/redis-server *
```

This is showing the port `6379` is actually being used by `redis-server`.

So why cannot it start then?

Do I need to add any inbound/outbound rules in AWS? Please help.

**UPDATE**

`ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis.conf --supervised systemd` command on terminal returns `bash: /etc/redis.conf: Permission denied`. Looks like need to give right permission to `/etc/redis.conf` file.

```
$ ls -l /etc/redis.conf
-rw-r-----. 1 redis redis 62189 Aug 26 03:04 /etc/redis.conf
```

So what permission do I need to give here? Who should own this file?

Comment: If its already running, maybe you want to `restart` it?

Comment: `restart` doesn't help either. Similar error. `Process: 5063 ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis.conf --supervised systemd (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 5063 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)`

Comment: Can you stop it `systemctl stop redis`? Maybe some config files are incorrect and it fails?

Comment: command runs, but upon checking the status same. "`Active: failed`" is that mean it is stopped?

Comment: yes. Something is wrong, config files maybe?

Comment: Although Redis is not running in the server, but my application throwing this error: `Connection to Redis 127.0.0.1:6379 failed after 2 failures. Last Error : (13) Permission denied`. Could it be a permission issue? How do I check correct permissions?